# openstreetmap daily updates with mysql

Tags: mysql, openstreetmap

Is there any good tool to import daily diffs into mysql?

I am using osmosis and retrieving region extracts but it takes around an hour to create the .osc file and update the database and I am pretty sure there are faster solutions out there as it only used to take 4-5 minutes on my postgis setup (Unfortunately I have to stick to MySQL and I can not switch back to Postgres)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, OSM and GIS in general rely on gespatial databases as Postgres+PostGIS and currently nobody reimplemented that level of functionality to MySQL https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/MySQL

Comment: Actually, MySQL has spatial support now. I used Osmosis to insert the planet file into it and it's working fine, it's just the daily updates I am having problems with.

Comment: Again, I can just tell you that MySQL has very bad tool support from GIS side and (at least) nobody can help you esp. on tuning the performance. Not because we are evil, it's just an lack of experience :/